# Entity Framework Core 2.0 Scaffold view from existing database

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

Is it possible to scaffold view from existing database in Entity Framework Core 2.0?

Something like command below:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=xxx;Database=xxx; User Id=xxx; Password=xxx;"  
                   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer        
                   -OutputDir Models -Context TestStare 
                   -Tables Osebe -Views View1 -Force
```

Comment: You don't have a .EDMX file with a schema of table in it ?

Comment: @AntoinePelletier, EF.Core doesn't use edmx files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not supported, currently in the Backlog: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/1679

Comment: It is however possible to use a view as a table. In particular, something along the lines of this: 
`public DbQuery<MyEntity> Entities { get { return Set<MyEntity>().AsNoTracking(); } }`. And then I build the entity in OnModelCreating(). To further restrict things down, I overridden SaveChanges to `public override int SaveChanges() => throw new InvalidOperationException();` but if you have editable tables in the same context that code would be.... less concise.

Comment: This is now supported. The answer provided by @AnAnita is correct in .NET Core 5

Answer (score 5):

From EF Core 3.0 it is possible to scaffold views and keyless entities 
Excerpt from [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/#reverse-engineering-of-database-views)

> Query types, which represent data that can be read from the database
>   but not updated, have been renamed to keyless entity types. As they
>   are an excellent fit for mapping database views in most scenarios, EF
>   Core now automatically creates keyless entity types when reverse
>   engineering database views.

Answer (score 4):

You not need to write -Views... just add the names of views to tables list...

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=xxx;Database=xxx; User Id=xxx; Password=xxx;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Context TestStare -Tables Osebe, View1 -Force
```

Comment: hm.. what is not working?

Comment: It does work. The caveat is that this will not "update" an existing entity structure but instead will create a new one. Best to run this into a temp directory and move the models and context definitions to your existing entity structure, as stated in other threads. And just an editorial note, the .NET framework offered so much better tools for managing data-first object modeling. This scaffolding stuff is just painful to use.

Comment: So the fact that it creates a new context is unnecessary. It is the same connection string to the server and database... I just had that problem @iGanja