# How to scaffold views and stored procedures from SQL Server to ASP.NET Core 2.2 project?

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.2, asp.net-core-scaffolding

I have an existing database in SQL Server that I need to connect to ASP.NET Core 2.2 project with EF Core. I scaffolded the models and the DbContext via the [Scaffold-DbContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell#scaffold-dbcontext) command in Package Manager Console. I can access all the data from the tables. However this didn't scaffold the procedures or the views.

This is a major obstacle to starting to use ASP.NET Core in our apps. Is there any way we could circumvent this? Can it be done in ASP.NET Core 2.2 or in a later version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stored procedure and view mapping is not currently supported in ef core scaffolding. You can track open issues respectively at [245](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/245) and [827](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/827).

Comment: Thanks Mustafa. Do you know how to circumvent this?

Comment: You can find some examples on the site like https://stackoverflow.com/a/44231306/3445247 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47417088/entity-framework-core-2-0-scaffold-view-from-existing-database#comment81794744_47419284

Comment: For anyone else with the same question as I did, here's a confirmation that this is available in preview 6 of .net core 3: 
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/1679#issuecomment-502360106

Answer (score 2):

> Can it be done in ASP.NET Core 2.2 or in a later version?

In .NET Core 3.1 (and seemingly 3.0) there is support for views. See [Reverse engineering of database views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/#reverse-engineering-of-database-views) in New features in Entity Framework Core 3.0.

It still uses `--table` or `-t`, or will be picked up with all the other tables and views if you don't pass particular tables/views.

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Connection-String-Information" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o ModelsFolderName -c DbContextName -d -v --table viewName
```

The name of the class will be prefixed with a `V`.