# Does EF Core reverse engineer SSMS views, not just tables?

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework-core

I've successfully used the following EF Core code to reverse engineer **tables**, for example:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=myserver,1433;Database=etl_mib;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models\ETL -Context Data\etl_mibContext -Tables po_dtl_p061
```

But when I try to do the exact same thing to reverse engineer **views**, I get an error stating it is "unable to find a table in the database matching the selected table..." when I know that I'm using the correct view name.

I'm reading that tables must have a primary key for EF to pick it up, and my views have primary keys from the underlying tables selected, so is that not enough? This article uses ISNULL() to trick it, but that isn't working for me either: https://girlfromoutofthisworld.com/entity-framework-and-setting-primary-keys-on-views/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework Core 2.0 Scaffold view from existing database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47417088/entity-framework-core-2-0-scaffold-view-from-existing-database)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible now in EF Core 3.0 by using keyless entity type. You can map a view using the reverse engineer tool Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools, it will create a keyless entity type for your view.

Using the Package Manager Console:

Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=SERVER_NAME;Initial Catalog=DB_NAME;Integrated Security=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Tables VIEW_NAME

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/#reverse-engineering-of-database-views